# std::string::clear() vs using another string

Tags: c++, string

I need a temporary string to append and modify pre-existing strings so that i can use with `DrawText`. That temporary string needs to change inside a function so I have 2 options:

-Use `std::string::clear()`

-Initialize another temporary string.

I can use and understand both methods but I'm wondering, which one is better?

Edit: To the function in question, having low running-time is essential

Comment: I have to say that while thinking about this I just realized that in comparison to DrawText, creating temporary string copies is extra cheap. Do you realize how much work DrawText has to do? It's massive.

Comment: Yeah i know that `DrawText` is a relativelly slow function, but that does not undermine my search to keep the rest of the function as fast as I can. Ty for the answer Zan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If (and only if) profiling reveals a performance problem in your function then you might save tiny amounts of time by reusing an existing string.

The memory of the existing string is already allocated. No new memory allocation needs to be made unless the string exceeds the size of the memory allocation.

On the other hand, if you create and destroy a lot of strings, the allocation time can start to add up.

I have some code where std::string allocation and copying dominates the profile. To fix it sometime in the future, we're going to have to implement string pooling, custom allocators and use string_ref instead of string.

So yes, it can be a problem. But measure to find out before trying to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

Whichever one more clearly reflects the intent of the code is better. The one you would use if you didn't stop to think which was "better" is better.

Comment: This depends on your goals. If you need more performance then the intent of the code doesn't matter. Clear code is useless when its too slow.